# Optimizing converting ObjectResult from stored procedure into a list

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

I am retrieving data from a SQL stored procedure and converting the results into a list. The conversion from ObjectResult to a list is extremely slow, about 40ms per element. I am trying to optimize the time to do this because it is happening in a web service call. Is there a faster way to convert an ObjectResult from a stored procedure into a list or anything?

```
ObjectResult<OV_GetUserStatusReports_Result> dataFromDB = context.OV_GetUserStatusReports(_currentUser.Username, lastSyncedDate);
var statusReports = dataFromDB.ToList();
```

Comment: How did you measure that the call to .ToList() is taking 40ms per result?

Comment: The database call is executed as a result of the ToList() statement. If you want to have all the results you have to optimize your database action by adding indexes, for example.

Comment: Jeroen is right. The profile had ToList as being slow but really it's because the database call is not executed until its result is used.